# How to plot ROC curve in python with text data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, roc

i want to plot the ROC curve in order to display the TPR versus FPR  using naiive model as classification.

I already vectorize my data.

when i run the code it display the below error:

> ```
> raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__}) sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted
> ```

## code:

```
#Create ROC curve
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pred_probas = pipeline.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
fpr,tpr,_ = roc_curve(y_test, pred_probas)
roc_auc = auc(fpr,tpr)
plt.plot(fpr,tpr,label='area = %.2f' %roc_auc)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.legend(loc='lower right')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pointing to `CountVectorizer` not ROC curve. This could be helpful [CountVectorizer: Vocabulary wasn't fitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674380/countvectorizer-vocabulary-wasnt-fitted)